# Angular 2 Conditional Loop with *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, loops

I am building IONIC 2 App and I need to integrate Slides in My App.

I am having loop conditional issue to implement in my HTML. Below is my current code given where loops output  content as many time the loop runs.

```
<!--categories_slider-->
  <div class="categories_slider english-font" *ngIf="homeCategories[3].content">
    <h4>{{homeCategories[3].name}}</h4>
    <!-- -->    
    <ion-slides pagination="true" autoplay="5000" loop="true" speed="1000" >
      <ng-container *ngFor="let slides of homeCategories[3].posts; let i = index">   
        <ion-slide>
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col col-4>
                <div class="categories_slider_image">                      
                  <wordpress-feature-media (click)="previewPost(slides)" *ngIf="slides.featured_media" [id]="slides.featured_media"></wordpress-feature-media>
                </div>
                <h5>{{slides.title.rendered}}</h5>
                <p [innerHtml]="slides.title.rendered"></p>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
        </ion-slide>
      </ng-container>
    </ion-slides>
  </div>
  <!--categories_slider end -->
```

What I need is to create the loop in a way so that for every **ion-slide** there can be three **ion-col** should output.

Like below;

```
<ion-slide>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-4></ion-col col-4>
            <ion-col col-4></ion-col col-4>
            <ion-col col-4></ion-col col-4>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-slide>
<ion-slide>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-4></ion-col col-4>
            <ion-col col-4></ion-col col-4>
            <ion-col col-4></ion-col col-4>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-slide>
```

How can I create conditional tags to achieve the desired result?

Thanks Sanny

Comment: I'm sure the code in this question could be reduced by 80% without losing any information relevant to the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Adding more information about what the expected result or behavior is would be helpful though. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I gave complete code for better understanding of my requirement...

Comment: IMHO it's mostly obfuscation ;-)

Comment: I reduced the code, are you able to understand now?

Comment: Yes, much better now :). I'd suggest to prepare a data structure in code that reflects the structure you want in the DOM and then use nested `*ngFor` to render the `<ion-slide><ion-grid><ion-row>` and in the inner `*ngFor` the `<ion-col>`.

Comment: I am very new with *ngFor & *ngIf and can not implement your instructions, can you give me code if possible?

Answer (score 0):

To give you better answer I would need more information, but basically you need to create an Array slides where you are going to store data for slides and display it with for loop.

```
<ion-slide *ngFor = slide of slides>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-4>{{ slide.title }}</ion-col col-4>
            <ion-col col-4>{{ slide.img }}</ion-col col-4>
            <ion-col col-4>{{ slide.something }}</ion-col col-4>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-slide>
```

I would create a component something like this

```
imports....;


class Slides {
    'title': string  = "";
    'img': string     = "";
    'something': string = "";
 }

@Component({
  selector: 'page-slides',
  templateUrl: 'slides.html'
})

export class SlidesPage {

  public slides: Slides = new Slides();

constructor....

...
this.slides.push({...})
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Sorry then i don't understand. You can try to explain again. I will delete the answer. Separate topic and suggestion. You should add ion-text to all p and h tags. Ionic will send you a warning if you don't put it.

Comment: See where I have set  *ngFor in my code but I want output in a different way to create the loop in a way so that for every ion-slide there can be three ion-col should output.